# Calling qsort comparator

Tags: c, qsort

I have a comparator function that returns 1, 0, or -1, declared as follows:

```
int multiPrecisionCompare(const DIGIT_T a[], const DIGIT_T b[], int32_t length);
```

where `DIGIT_T` is `int8_t`.

I want to call a function `qsort` but I have a problem understanding what I have to change or how to call the comparator function inside.

```
qsort(bigArray->x, 8,30 , <-what here?????->);


    i

int multiprecisionCompare(const DIGIT_T a[], const DIGIT_T b[], int32t length) 
{
  while(length--) { // little endian
if(a[length] > b[length])
  return 1;
if(a[length] < b[length])
  return -1;
}

return 0;
}


point * bigArray = (point *)(malloc(K*sizeof(point)));
CreateListAndOrder( lots of parameters) // this fills the bigArray unsorted
/* point is a structure of X,Y,Z where each of this is DIGIT_T */
qsort((void *)bigArray, K, sizeof(point), cmp);
```

I want to sort it according to X coordinate, but that is solved by int32t length, that it should compare only first coordinate from that struct

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return multiPrecisionCompare((const DIGIT_T*)a, (const DIGIT_T*)b,  DIGIT_LENGTH);
    //return multiPrecisionCompare(*(const DIGIT_T**)a, *(const DIGIT_T**)b,  DIGIT_LENGTH);
}
```

Comment: `struct data { DIGIT_T *n; int32_t length; };`.. `int multiPrecisionCompare(const struct data *a, const struct data *b);` or `length` pass to compare function by Global variable.

Comment: Does your compiler support `qsort_s(base, nmemb, size,
compar, context);`?

Comment: Show `point`. maybe `return multiPrecisionCompare(((point*)a)->x, ((point*)b)->x,  DIGIT_LENGTH);`

Comment: typedef struct {
 DIGIT_T x[length];
 DIGIT_T y[length];
 DIGIT_T z[length];
} point;

length is defined as constant number.

I have tried the latest change but it is still comparing the addresses not the values

Answer (score 2):

`qsort` accepts a pointer to a function with the following signature:

```
int cmp(void const *, void const *)
```

You have to adjust your comparison function, to match this signature, and than simply pass in a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(DIGIT_T *)a - *(DIGIT_T *)b );
}

qsort(bigArray->x, 8, 30 , cmpfunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int multiPrecisionCompare(const DIGIT_T a[], const DIGIT_T b[], int32_t length);
int32_t DIGIT_LENGTH;
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return multiPrecisionCompare(((point*)a)->x, ((point*)b)->x, DIGIT_LENGTH);
}

DIGIT_LENGTH = length;
point * bigArray = (point *)malloc(K*sizeof(point));
//fills the bigArray unsorted
qsort(bigArray, K, sizeof(point), cmp);
```

Comment: This looks good but for some reason when I debug I have found out that in multiPrecisionCompare function that is called is the value that is compared the adress of the pointer, not the value where the pointer is pointing, that should be easy to fix but I am struggling, too much for today I guess :D

Comment: @user3411282 `qsort` gives a pointer to an element in the comparison function.

Comment: I have done it the way you posted it but it was not working , it wasnt sorting so I went step by step in debug and I have found out it is not working, because somehow in the final multiPrecisionCompare function which is called through cmp function is comparing value of pointers, not values of the objects where it is pointing to :)

Comment: _i will edit the first post to make it more clear_ yes, you do it.

Comment: is it working for you with malloc as well ? I cant use static array because my K will be around 1 million ( i am actually doing babystep giantstep for elliptic curve of order (1000000)^2) and i run out of stack memory, it must be on heap

Comment: @user3411282 It's same as using  malloc, of course.  try `point * bigArray = (point *)(malloc(K*sizeof(point)));
 point ini[3] = { ...};
 memcpy(bigArray, ini, sizeof(ini));`